# Declaring and instantiating variables locally vs globally?

Tags: java, variables, global-variables, local-variables

When I create and instantiate a variable locally, it will be created and instantiated everytime the method is called. It means that if I call the method 100 times, the variable will be created and instantiated 100 times. But it also ensures that the variable is created and instantiated only when need.

```
public class ClassA {
    public int generateRandom(int range) {
        Random rand = new Random(); // creating and instantiating variable locally
        return rand.nextInt(range);
    }
}
```

I can also create the variable globally so that it will be created and instantiated only once. The global variables can also be shared among different methods as well. But it will be occupying memory till the time the class is in scope.

```
class ClassA {
    Random rand = new Random(); // creating and instantiating variable globally
    public int generateRandom(int range) {
        return rand.nextInt(range);
    }
}
```

Creating and instantiating is a time consuming process but we also have to take memory into consideration. Then come the concepts of code readability, adaptability and maintainability.
I can have tens and hunderds of variable in my code. 
I will like to know the best practices that are out there and also which is prefered more: memory-management or time-management.

Comment: Best Practice: *Don't optimize performance as long as you don't have performance issues.* - As soon as you let's say read data from a file or send a request to a Web API, the performance impact of a class member vs a method-local variable will be insignificant. Instead base your decision on design or implementation requirements.

Comment: *which is prefered more: memory-management or time-management*.  Neither. You have already enumerated the most important factors: *readability, adaptability and maintainability*.  Performance should only be a consideration if and when it becomes an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a variable depends on what you intend to do with this variable and how do you want it to behave and live inside the lifecycle of your application.

An attribute instantiated inside your method will only live during the execution time  your method, its scope and lifecycle is tied to the method, once your method execution is done, the attribute is destroyed and the memory behind it is free. If your attribute is to be used only for this one particular method the good way is to instanciate it inside that method.

Now, creating a variable as a Class attribute is different, you create a strong dependency between the class and that attribute and also, it gives your Class a "State", which means if you consider having a `ClassA` instance, the `rand` attribute inside will have a particular state tied to it that will be modified each time rand is modified. This time, the lifecycle of `rand` is tied to `ClassA`. Here `rand` **IS NOT** a global varible, it is a class variable.

If you want an approach with a global variable, either consider using a `static` field, Or using Dependency Injection via a Framework such as Spring that allows you to have what's called "beans" which is a single instance of your variable shared across all your application.